# Moving WordPress default menus in admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been digging around the codex trying to find a way to move the default menus around in the admin area. specifically i want to take the customizer from the appearance menu and move it to my custom menu. same with other menus. Is there a list somewhere of for them or a file to edit with the orders or way to move them. I don't want to edit any core files though as obviously will break on any update.

I already have my own menu: [image of own menu](http://prnt.sc/a4epr1) code is below for mine.

```
function dcmaintheme_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'dcmaintheme_adminpage', 'Dragon Cove Theme', 'manage_options', 'dcmaintheme_adminpage', 'dcmaintheme_page', content_url( 'themes/dragon-cove-base/img/icon.png' ), 10 );
    add_submenu_page( 'dcmaintheme_adminpage', 'Admin Options', 'Admin Options', 'manage_options', 'submenu_adminoptions_page', 'submenu_adminoptions_page' );
```

what id like to get is another sub-menu that links to say the appearance->customiser and have it in my custom menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-admin-ui-customize/), it will allow you to customize the **Admin Toolbar** and the **Admin Side menu**. You can choose what content on the menu to display to a specific user role.

Comment: rather not use plugins i'm trying to avoid as much reliance on plugins as possible and also more interested in learning how WordPress does things under the hood.

Comment: To add an admin menu item you can refer to [this documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/), there is two methods, the first one needs to create a custom plugin et the second i think that you can add the code to your `functions.php`. For removing a menu page you can refer to [this documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page). The best way is to create your custom plugin, you can reuse it.

Comment: Ive already created my menu and it works, just want to move some of the default options in WordPress to new locations if possible. i'll update the main post in a sec with more info.